# How to pipe stream to java program?

Tags: java, cmd

Under cmd.exe, I can do like this:

```
dir *.*|grep ....
```

I want to do this to java program

```
dir *.i|java test
```

What I should do in my java test class?

Answer (score 1):

You would process the [System.in](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) stream and capture/process whatever the source program (`dir` in this case) provides.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `System.in` in `Test` class,here is the example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream in = System.in;
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int next = in.read();
            while (next > -1) {
                bos.write(next);
                next = in.read();
            }
            bos.flush();
            byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
            System.out.println("output:" + new String(bytes));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```